# drupal ctools multistep wizard

Tags: drupal, drupal-ctools

i am trying to write a ctools multistep wizard, here is my wizard function;

```
function _mymodule_adv_wizard($js=NULL, $step="step1") {

  $form_info = array();
  $form_info["id"]              = SK_ADV_WIZARD_ID;
  $form_info["path"]            = "tests/adv/mymodule/%step";

  $form_info["show trail"]      = TRUE;
  $form_info["show back"]       = TRUE;
  $form_info["show cancel"]     = TRUE;
  $form_info["show return"]     = TRUE;

  $form_info["next callback"]   = "_my_module_adv_wizard_on_next";
  $form_info["finish callback"] = "_my_module_adv_wizard_on_finish";
  $form_info["cancel callback"] = "_my_module_adv_wizard_on_cancel";

  $form_info["order"]           = array("step1" => t("Stap 1"), "step2" => t("Stap 2"), "step3" => t("Stap 3"), "step4" => t("Stap 4"), "step5" => t("Stap 5"), "step6" => t("Stap 6"), "step7" => t("Stap 7"), "step8" => t("Stap 8"));

  $form_info["forms"]           = array(); 
  $form_info["forms"]["step1"]  = array("form id" => "_my_module_adv_step1_form");
  $form_info["forms"]["step2"]  = array("form id" => "_my_module_adv_step2_form");
  $form_info["forms"]["step3"]  = array("form id" => "_my_module_adv_step3_form");
  $form_info["forms"]["step4"]  = array("form id" => "_my_module_adv_step4_form");
  $form_info["forms"]["step5"]  = array("form id" => "_my_module_adv_step5_form");
  $form_info["forms"]["step6"]  = array("form id" => "_my_module_adv_step6_form");
  $form_info["forms"]["step7"]  = array("form id" => "_my_module_adv_step7_form");
  $form_info["forms"]["step8"]  = array("form id" => "_my_module_adv_step8_form");

  $form_state = array("ajax" => FALSE, "object_id" => SK_ADV_OBJECT_ID, "object" => new stdClass());

  //initialize ctools wizard
  ctools_include("wizard");
  $form = ctools_wizard_multistep_form($form_info, $step, $form_state); 
  return theme('my_module_wrapper', array('formwrapper'  =>  $form, 'page'  =>  $step));
}
```

Everything is fine and i can access pages seperately but the buttons don't get printed so i can't go to the submit and validate functions. I have another wizard with diff. id and form defs but it works like a charm. What could be the reason.

p.s. all functions and variables are declared in the code above.

Answer (score 3):

Do you reset the form-array at your first step?

```
function _my_module_adv_step1_form($form, &$form_state){
    $form = array(); // this remove your submit-buttons. Delete this line and your bottons will appear.
    //... your form elements...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer but posting as an answer because comment box is not enough for this.*

My best guessing is that you need to add the buttons on your won.

```
function _my_module_adv_step1_form($form, &$form_state){
  ... your form elements...
  $form['next'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Next'),
    '#submit' => array('_my_module_adv_wizard_on_next'),
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, this would be a solution but normally, ctools wizard renders buttons automatically. the strange thing is i have another wizard in the same module and it has buttons. i am debugging in the wizard.inc of ctools and i can confirm that the buttons get inserted in the form array. getting mad!!!!